# How can I access a memory buffer mapped into a swift structure?

Tags: c, swift, pointers, struct, unsafemutablepointer

This is probably trivial for you, but I am new in Swift and I can't find the answer.  I use C code to convert data from TCP/IP, that all works fine.  But when I try to send the data back to Swift, I get the error:
Value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' has no member 'x'
(at compile time).

Put simply, my C code generates a structure that I want my swift code to read and use a structure to access the fields.
Note: I DO NOT WANT TO COPY THE DATA (the example here is simple but I deal with MBs (GB).

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
  struct MyStruct1
  {
    var x   : UInt32        
    var y   : UInt32
  }
  var buffer : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?
  //...
  buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate( capacity: Int(1024) )
  if (buffer != nil)
  {
     defer { buffer!.deallocate() }
     // CCode_That_Initializes_Buffer( buffer ) with An array of MyStruct
     var myStructP : UnsafeMutablePointer<MyStruct1>
     myStructP = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(buffer!).assumingMemoryBound(to: MyStruct1.self)
     // Value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<MyStruct1>' has no member 'x'
     print( myStructP.x ) // <= This does not compile
  }
}
```

Comment: `UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity)` returns a non-optional, so your forward declaration of `buffer` as optional, the check against `nil` and the force wrapping thereafter don't do anything.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.  If I remove the "!" from the buffer! the compilers complains a lot (presumingly because it is an optional; isn't it?).  Or perhaps I do not understand the usage of the word optional.  Any way, without a code sample from you, I do not know what you mean in and how to find a solution.  Thank you for trying to help me.  I am still looking to understand and fix my code...

Comment: My comment wasn't a solution (hence why I didn't put it below as an answer), it's merely a comment on the unnecessary complexity introduced by declaring `buffer` as `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?`. Given that you made `buffer` optional, some form of unwrapping is necessary (force unwrapping with `!` being one of the options, although usually the worst choice), but that could be completely circumvented if buffer was just made non-optional `var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 1024)`

Comment: What's the ownership model behind the data you get from C land? Who's responsible for deallocating it? (e.g. is it loaned out to you with the guarantee that it'll be valid for the duration of your use, and then automatically cleaned up on the C side, or are you given ownership and the responsibility to `free` it whenever is appropriate for you?)

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your additional comments.  The code I provided is not my real code, but it has the same structure.  I need to have a buffer that can be reallocated and grow as needed by the data coming from tcpip, and I need to deallocate it if the device runs low in memory. => What I need is help to understanding how to give the pointer of the buffer to Swift to access that generated memory using Swift struct.  I still don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can dereference a `UnsafeMutablePointer<MyStruct1>` to get a `MyStruct1` using the `pointee` field, but then you're dealing with Swift struct land, where every assignment and passing as a parameter can cause a copy. It's possible to work with this, but I would advise against it. Is there a particular reason you're doing your networking with C code, rather than just using Swift's own NIO?

Comment: You could conceviably make a `MyStruct1Ptr` struct, which wraps a `UnsafeMutablePointer<MyStruct1>`, and exposes the same properties as `MyStruct1Ptr`, but as computed properties. E.g. `myStruct1Ptr.foo` is a computed property that calls `self.ptr.pointee.foo`. It'd be a pain though.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the bulk of this data? I suspect that your struct is some kind of header/metadata, and some kind of array that contains the bulk of the data. In that case, copy the struct isn't an issue, it's just the buffer that you need to reuse, which is possible with Unsafe(Raw)(Mutable)Buffer

Comment: I do not know how to use pointee.  I will look into this.

Comment: The real structure I get from tcpip can be of practically any length from 3 bytes and above.  I was able to have Swift read my C structures (through the magic of Bridging-Header.h).  The C code is shared with a a Windows server.  Let me learn about pointee...

Comment: "The real structure I get from tcpip can be of practically any length from 3 bytes and above." The only way to create C structs of varying runtime size is to use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), which can't possibly be the case here, because Swift doesn't support such types. Thus, these structs are a constant size, and contain their payload indirectly, as some buffer elsewhere in memory. In such a case, copying the structs themselves isn't an issue for copying (they'd be some constant-sized overhead), but rather, the payload.

Comment: I learned (again) about pointee and it seems to only return the numerical value of a pointer which is not my problem.  I seems to get the pointer, my problem seems to have swift assign that pointer to a pointer of a typed structure in swift.

Comment: Hi Alexander.  Remember I get my data from tcpip?  For example, I may get a 'here is a filename' packet.  I will map the header into a struct and deal with the variable filename another way.  I would like to focus on my problem now:  assigning a memory to a swift struct pointer.  Good night.

Comment: "it seems to only return the numerical value of a pointer which is not my problem." No it doesn't, it derefences a given pointer, akin to `*p` in C. `UnsafePointer<T>.pointee` gives you the referenced `T`.

Comment: `Remember I get my data from tcpip?` Well you mention it abstractly, TCP/IP is a networking protocol stack, so telling someone you get your data from it is like saying you got your data by pen and paper. It doesn't explain much about the details of what's going on or how it's done. `I will map the header into a struct` -> Is this the struct you're trying to access in Swift land? If it's just a header, why is copying it such a concern? `deal with the variable filename another way.` and I presume this isn't part of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot map a buffer allocated as an unsafe raw pointer into a Swift structure variable without copying.

A Swift structure variable has other language properties such that you can only access the contents of a Swift structure variable via a pointer if that variable has been allocated by Swift as that same structure type (e.g. not as an unsafe pointer handed to it by C).

Instead, you might be able to write accessor functions that use the offset and size of each Swift structure element to read and write bytes from an offset raw pointer bound to a variable of the required type.

Or just use the C structure via a bridging header.